# Ajax Load + Refresh the same div

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

Snippet code to load the content of the template into the div (main.html):

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content_pane').load( href );


<a href="/main" class="active"> MAIN  </a>
<a href="/review"> REVIEW </a>

<div id="#content_pane"> </div>
```

review.html:

```
<a href="review/1" class="pageLink"> 1 </a>
<a href="review/2" class="pageLink"> 2 </a>
```

**My question now is that:**

1. Let's say, I've loaded the review page into the div #content_pane by clicking on href="/review"
2. Part of the review content, contains the href link of page numbers.
3. **QUESTION !!** When I click on those link (page number), I want the content of the link clicked on this review page to be loaded back into this div #content_pane with the AJAX effect just like the jQuery load like above.

**EDIT**

**Current Problem:**

The class .pageLink from review.html is not accessible from main.html, after review.html being loaded into div #content_pane

Can anyone help on this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by following:

1. The div element in main.html loads review.html.
2. review.html can access the div element in main.html.
3. Hence, any links clicked on review.html, jQuery/javascript can be performed to refresh the div in main.html.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if I understood you correctly,
You want a way to load more content after the ajax call for those links has finished.
For this (If your using jQuery) I would do this:
You will need to use :".delegate()" function. (for more info read [here](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)).
**Now for the code:**

```
<script>
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('#content_pane').load( href );
$('#content_pane').delegate('#your-link-id-here', 'click', function(){
var href2 = $('.your-link-class-here').attr('href');
$('#content_pane').load( href2 );//If you want your links to stay, put another div insted of content_pane.
});
</script>

<a href="/main" class="active"> MAIN  </a>
<a href="/review"> REVIEW </a>

<div id="#content_pane"> </div>
```

Comment: I think I understood your approach. But it seemed to have fixed the link id there.

What if I actually do not know in advance how many links are there until the review content is loaded ?

Comment: @MrCooL, How does the number of links change the situation exactly? My code is quite generic, that means that it does not need the number of links. Edit: Ok I think I got your problem, I changed the link-id.. to a class, then you could have multiple links.

Comment: I've edited my question with the problem description. I think this is somehow solves my requirement of having ajax experience to load the same DIV. However, as I've explained for the problem, it couldn't access the class from the review.html

Comment: Can you give me the full source code? I tried myself, but the load didn't function for some reason(even on my server).